# Swift not recognising new elements from JSON in LazyHStack

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, uikit

Hey guys so I have a problem with decoding JSON. I decoded the entire string and made a statement in the ViewModel which fetches only elements as such

```
@Published var posts = [Post]()
    var postsid6: [Post] {
        var typeid6posts = [Post]()
        for post in self.posts { if post.type_id == "6" { typeid6posts.append(post) }
            
        }
         return typeid6posts
        
    }
```

So if it's type_id="6" it fetches them seperetly and I call the function like this

```
 LazyHStack(alignment: .center){
                
                    ForEach(viewModel.postsid6) { post in
                        NavigationLink(destination: StoryDetailsView(post)) {
                            SingleStoryView(post: post, dateFormatter: viewModel.dateFormatter)
                                .padding(.bottom, 16)
                        }
                    
                    
                    }
                    
                    }
```

Problem is for some reason swift fetches only 2 of them and there are 7 in the JSON with type_id="6"

This is the entire ViewModel. Posts are being updated but the typeid6posts isn't adding new ones

```
//
//  PostsViewModel.swift
//  EMDC App (iOS)
//
//  Created by admin on 19.6.21..
//

import Foundation

class PostsViewModel: ObservableObject{
    lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
        df.timeStyle = .short
        df.dateStyle = .short
        return df
    }()
    
    struct PostsResponse: Codable{
        let items: [Post]
        let users: [String : UserModel]
    }
    
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    var postsid6: [Post] {
        var typeid6posts = [Post]()
        for post in self.posts { if post.type_id == "6" { typeid6posts.append(post) }
            
        }
         return typeid6posts
        
    }
    
    var videibgt: [Post] {
        var videiisat = [Post]()
        for post in self.posts { if (post.videourl != nil) == true { videiisat.append(post) } }
         return videiisat
    }

    private let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    func fetchPosts(){
        let url = URL(string: "https://cdn.rapttor.com/influencer/data/2/posts.json")!
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            do{
                let decoded = try self.jsonDecoder.decode(PostsResponse.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let posts = decoded.items
                   
                    
                    var postsWithUser = [Post]()
                    
                    for var post in posts{
                        post.user = decoded.users[post.userId]!
                        postsWithUser.append(post)
                    }
                    self.posts.append(contentsOf: postsWithUser)
                
                    print(self.posts.count)
                    
                    
                }
                
              
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
    func duplicate(){
        posts.append(contentsOf: posts)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to update your view with new contents of `postsid6` every time `posts` is updated? If so, `postsid6` needs to be `@Published` as well. It will have to be a stored property, you can update it in the setter of `posts`

Comment: you say "..Swift not recognising new elements from JSON in LazyHStack" and  "..I have a problem with decoding JSON", but you do not show any json decoding code. Show us the relevant code.

Comment: Is this `Post ` identifiable? what's the identifier

Comment: I've added the entire ViewModel for clarification

Comment: You still don't have a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that @lorem ipsum suggested in the first place. If you don't understand what this means, take the code you have posted, open a new project, paste it in and see if it compiles at all. You have left out a lot of important implementation details and no one can help you without them. My suspicion is you have instantiated your model incorrectly, but I have no real idea without your implementation.